# Busybox, netstat, no -p

Tags: linux, linux-networking, busybox, embedded-linux

I have an ultra old (don't ask why) BusyBox *(BusyBox v1.01 (2008.12.19-21:31+0000) Built-in shell (ash))* on my DreamBox. I would like to find out which process opened which connection using netstat. But I found out that BusyBox's netstat doesn't contain the *-p* option. What other possibilites do I have to find out which process has opened (and is using) the corresponding socket?

Comment: Is lsof part of that version of busybox?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find the equivalent information in slightly uglier form (a.k.a. hexadecimal) in `/proc/net/tcp`.  There, you can find the inode of the connection, which you can look up under `/proc/$pid/fd/`.

For example:

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcp
sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
 0: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 6115 1 f5adc4c0 300 0 0 2 -1
...
```

(In normal netstat, but not in busybox netstat, the `-e` option also gives you that extra information.)

You can find the process which corresponds to the inode with the following command:

```
# for x in $(find /proc/ | grep /fd/); do ls -la $x 2>/dev/null; done | grep 6115
...
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  7 jan 22.50 /proc/2560/fd/3 -> socket:[6115]
```

You need root access for the second step.

Not as convenient as the `-p` option, obviously, but works in a bind.  Could be scripted, if necessary.

Comment: Sounds cool, but my netstat doesn't work as it should, it outputs nothing additional with the **-e** option. I have 6 columns also with **-e**: Proto, Recv-Q, Send-Q, Local Address, Foreign Address, State. Is there a way with the ports? I can see the port..

Comment: You're right, I must have messed up my tests.  I edited it to give you a working solution.

Comment: How do you find the number "2560" you type in your second command? That's the question.

Comment: @ygoe you have to use `6115` and use it like this: `find /proc/ -type l | grep /fd/ | xargs ls -la 2>/dev/null | grep 6115`

Comment: You'll need a semicolon after the `2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

This may not help, if you don't have the opportunity to rebuild Busybox, but in case it helps anyone...

Busybox does have a configuration option to support the `-p` switch of [Busybox `netstat`](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#netstat). See option `CONFIG_FEATURE_NETSTAT_PRG`, selected in busybox menuconfig via **Networking Utilities → netstat → Enable PID/Program name output**.

Answer (score 3):

If you have or can get `ss` on your device it can show you the PID too:

```
ss -ltp # for TCP
ss -lup # for UDP
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variant that might be easier for some:

1. Identify interesting protocol and port from netstat or other source
2. Convert port to hex: echo  | awk '{ printf "%x\n", $1 }'
3. cd /proc/net
4. grep -i <hex_port> {upd|tcp} | awk '{ printf "local: %s inode: %s", $2, $10 }'
   If you get multiple lines, look for the one that has the matching hex_port in the second half of the "local" string.
5. ls -al /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep

This should return a line similar to:
lrwx------    1 root     root            64 May 22 20:02 /proc/1148/fd/26 -> socket:[4520]

Telling you that PID 1148 has a socket open on inode 4520

Example: Looking for the SSDP process on a Philips Hue Bridge V2.x:

```
root@Philips-hue:/proc# netstat -an | grep 1900
udp     2176      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           
root@Philips-hue:/proc# echo 1900 | awk '{ printf "%x\n", $1 }'
76c
root@Philips-hue:/proc# grep -i 76c /proc/net/udp | awk '{ printf "local: %s ino
de: %s\n", $2, $10 }'
local: 00000000:076C inode: 4520
root@Philips-hue:/proc# ls -al /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep 4520
lrwx------    1 root     root            64 May 22 20:02 /proc/1148/fd/26 -> socket:[4520]
```

So we identified process PID=1148 as the listener:

```
root@Philips-hue:/proc# ps w | grep 1148
 1148 root     64016 S    /usr/sbin/ipbridge -p /home/ipbridge/var -z /dev/ttyZigbee -u /etc/channel/channel-config -h /home -e ecb
 1696 root      1284 S    grep 1148
```

So now I know that the ipbridge daemon controls the SSDP listener among the many other things it controls on the Hue Bridge.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete awk script for it. It's ugly but it works.

```
{ cat /proc/net/tcp; lsof; } | awk -vMACH=$(uname -m) 'BEGIN { if (MACH == "i686") { M=-2; B=7; } else { M=2; B=1 } } function addr(a) { if (a) { return sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d:%d", "0x" substr(a, M*0+B, 2), "0x" substr(a, M*1+B, 2), "0x" substr(a, M*2+B, 2), "0x" substr(a, M*3+B, 2), "0x" substr(a, 10, 4)); } } substr($0,5,1)==":" { sock[$10]=$0; next } $3~/socket:/ { if (match($3, /[0-9]+/) == 0) { exit; } l = sock[substr($3, RSTART, RLENGTH)]; print $0 " " addr(substr(l, 7, 13)) " " addr(substr(l, 21, 13)) }'
```